# What does list in crontab do?

Tags: linux, command-line, cron, mailman

I'm maintaining a server which runs mailman. In it I find a crontab which looks like the following:

```
0 8 * * * list [ -x /usr/lib/mailman/cron/checkdbs ] && /usr/lib/mailman/cron/checkdbs
0 9 * * * list [ -x /usr/lib/mailman/cron/disabled ] && /usr/lib/mailman/cron/disabled
...
```

When I type *list* I get

> No command 'list' found ..

My searches for "crontab list", "linux list command", "mailman cron list" bring up results for listing things.

What does list in crontab do ?

What command is list refering to ?

Comment: What version of mailman is this ?  2.1.15-21 here and no use of 'list' on the mailman crontab.

Comment: is it an /etc crontab where 'list' is supposed to be a user that it runs as?

Comment: using mailman version 2.1.14

Comment: can't edit my last post..

cronjobs came as result from: crontab -ulist -l

I did not know that you * * * * * [user] command syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines in the system crontab (which is what I think you're looking at) have six fixed fields plus a command, in the form:

```
minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week user command
```

This is different from the per-user crontab which lacks the `user` field.

My guess is that `list` is the mailman user on that system.  This user is usually called `mailman`, but for whatever reason someone thought `list` was better (more generic?).

Comment: Thanks. I did not know user could be put in front of command. It's generic and confusing.